# JS String not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I am creating file paths like so:

```
'/Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy/VGimages/'+deviceName+'.png'
```

these file paths are passed to a function as parameters, this function uses the file path to perform a command on the terminal.

However, this string seems to split into 2 parts when used by the function. presenting this error:

```
exec error: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c adb pull /sdcard/nexLogin.png /Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy/VGimages/josh
.png

/bin/sh: line 1: .png: command not found
```

this is because '.png' has been separated from the main string.

Comment: deviceName may contain line break or something.. but please post your question and your efforts in resolving the issue

Comment: there is no space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the new line character from the end of the `deviceName` variable. You should probably use [the `trim` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to do this.

```
'/Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy/VGimages/'
+ deviceName.trim()
+ '.png'
```

Comment: thanks, solved the error above now I have a new one. not related however, cannot seem to find the newly created image but it did before with hardcoded names.